# Django - how to know in clean method if the form-data is new or if old data is being changed

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I know in MyForm.clean() whether the data is new, or if already saved data is being modifed?

What should is_this_new_data() look like in the following code?

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        if is_this_new_data(self):
            # perform some checks if this is new data
        else:
            # do nothing if this is data being modifed
            return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check `self.cleaned_data['some_field']` against `self.instance.some_field`.

A quick way to check if the object is new is to see if `self.instance.pk` has a value. It will be `None` unless the object already exists.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this worked. I'm surprised that there is no mention of this in the Django doc. I had gone through the docs and queried google without luck.

Comment: I believe this doesn't work if you're using a uuid as your id (or some other id type not generated by the database) because the id is then created at object initialization time instead of database row creation time.

Answer (score 7):

In the `clean` you can access the `changed_data` attribute, which is a list of the names of the fields which have changed.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data:
    for field_name in self.changed_data:
        # loop through the fields which have changed
        print "field %s has changed. new value %s" % (field_name, cleaned_data[field_name])
        do_something()
    return cleaned_data
```